# How to use SED or AWK instead of GREP as it is taking lot of time in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I wrote the below code to extract the testcase name and the PASSED/FAILED status.
**The testcase log is like below:** : In between there are so many lines.

I just want to extract the testcase name ( say A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000 and it's PASSED or FAILED status).

Also, another concern is : I have used grep, which is taking a longer time, to execute the shell script.

I need to use AWK or SED commands to solve the below problem.

One more thing I need is : I need to print ALL the failed testcases names like:

```
failed testcases list:

A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0002 Failed
A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0003 Failed
A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0004 Failed
```

```
Begin of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000 
Passed
End of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000 
Begin of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0002
FAILED
End of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0002
```

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter the logfilename : "
read logfilename
echo "Entered name : $logfilename"
echo "outside the while loop"
let success=0
let failure=0
let total=0
DONE=false
until $DONE; do
read line || DONE=true
    echo "$line" | grep "Begin of "
    if (echo "$line" | grep -i "PASSED") then
        ((success++))
    fi
    if (echo "$line" | grep -i "FAILED") then
        ((failure++))
    fi
    if (echo "$line" | grep "End of ") then
        ((total++))
    fi  
done < "$logfilename"   
echo "Total testcases : $total"
echo "Total testcase with Success : $success"
echo "Total testcase with Failure : $failure"
```

Hi Bodo:

I added the below lines alogn with your code:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the logfilename : "
read logfilename
echo "Entered name : $logfilename"
echo "outside the while loop"

awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; }
/^begin of / { print; count=1; passed=failed=0;}
/^end of / { count=0; totalcount++; if(failed)failcount++;else if(passed)passcount++;}
/passed/ && count { passed=1; }
/failed/ && count { failed=1; }
END {
  print "Total testcases : " totalcount;
  print "Total testcase with Success : " passcount;
  print "Total testcase with Failure : " failcount; }' "logfilename"
```

Hi Wrutel,

Could you please correct the below code:
I was trying to chomp off the line "Begin of TESTCASENAME" and just trying to store the FAILED testcases in an array and later print the list of failed testcases.
Also, I was trying to handle, the case - what if logfile is not present:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -a arr
# if no command line argument is given
# set logfilename to : logfilename not specified
if [ -z $0 ]
then
  logfilename="*** Log filename not specified.***"
elif [ -n $1 ]
then
# otherwise make first arg as logfilename
  logfilename=$1
fi

echo "outside the while loop"
let success=0
let failure=0
let total=0
let fail=0
while read line; do
        case "$line" in
                *Begin\ of\ *)  echo $line;;
                *PASSED*)       ((success++));;
                *FAILED*)       ((failure++))
                    arr[$fail] = $line
                    echo "Shubhra added this line : ${arr[$fail]}"
                    ((fail++));;
                *End\ of\ *)    ((total++));;
        esac
done < "$logfilename"

echo "Total testcases : $total"
echo "Total testcase with Success : $success"
echo "Total testcase with Failure : $failure"
echo "failed testcase list:"
echo ${arr[@]}
```

Comment: Your problem is not `grep` being slow, but the way your script is written. For example, instead of incrementing your "success" value slowly, you could do it in one go: `grep -i "success" | wc -l`. I feel like it would be way more performant if the entire script was designed this way, instead of being a giant for-each loop.

Comment: @Panki I need the testcase name (A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000) and against the name I need to write failed or passed. How to use wc -l and extracting testcase name together in a single command, pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to use builtin commands in the shell, as then there are not multiple fork/execs per line being done, which are relatively very expensive.

I would do it like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the logfilename : "
read logfilename
echo "Entered name : $logfilename"
echo "outside the while loop"
let success=0
let failure=0
let total=0
failedtests=()

while read line; do
        case "$line" in
                *Begin\ of\ *)  echo $line
                                failedtests+=( ${line/Begin of /} )
                                ;;
                *PASSED*)       ((success++));;
                *FAILED*)       ((failure++));;
                *End\ of\ *)    ((total++));;
        esac
done < "$logfilename"

echo "Total testcases : $total"
echo "Total testcase with Success : $success"
echo "Total testcase with Failure : $failure"
echo "Failed tests:" ${failedtests[@]}
```

You can use `case` to match glob patterns. According to your example data (which has "Passed" and not "PASSED" which you grep for) the leading `*` of each pattern could be left out, however with it, it matches the grep usage exactly.

I've also done away with the `DONE` variable, as you loop over the final empty string (resulting from the end-of-file) uselessly.

EDIT:
Added collecting and showing the failed tests. These are collected in the bash array `failedtests`. The `${line/Begin of /}` results in the contents of `line` with that string removed. Finally the complete contents of the array are shown with `${failedtests[@]}`.

Comment: @wrutel : could you please add the code, so that ALL the failed testcase names are listed ? The testcase name we can pick and process from the "Begin of testcasename" line or from "End of testcase name line"

Comment: @wrutel : Can you write code, to chomp off the "=====Begin of Testcasename=====". I just need the testcase name from that line and display trhe failed testcases list only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following script if your AWK supports the variable `IGNORECASE` to force case insensitive comparisons. (GNU AWK, e.g. on Linux supports this.)

If your AWK doesn't support `IGNORECASE`, you could

- modify all match patterns to case insensitive patterns, e.g. `/[Pp][Aa][Ss][Ss][Ee][Dd]/` instead of `/passed/` etc. or
- use function `tolower` with the value to be matched, e.g. `tolower($0) ~ /passed/` instead of `/passed/` etc.

```
awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; }
/^begin of / { print; count=1; passed=failed=0;}
/^end of / { count=0; totalcount++; if(failed)failcount++;else if(passed)passcount++;}
/passed/ && count { passed=1; }
/failed/ && count { failed=1; }
END {
  print "Total testcases : " totalcount;
  print "Total testcase with Success : " passcount;
  print "Total testcase with Failure : " failcount; }' logfile
```

With this input (in file `logfile`)

```
Begin of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000
Passed
foo
End of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000
Begin of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0002
bar
passed
FAILED
End of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0002
Begin of foo
failed
End of bar
foo
Passed
FAILED
bar
```

I get this result

```
Begin of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDSCONT_0000
Begin of A_HL_INT_GPRS_CGDCONT_0002
Begin of foo
Total testcases : 3
Total testcase with Success : 1
Total testcase with Failure : 2
```

Notes:
The edited version of the script counts `passed` or `failed` only once between `begin of ...` and `end of ...` lines, `failed` takes precedence over `passed`.
The script does not check that the identifiers in `begin of ...` and `end of ...` match.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the below error :$ ./test4.sh
Enter the logfilename : testlog.log
Entered name : testlog.log
outside the while loop
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `logfilename' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: @ShubhraGarg WIthout seeing your script `test4.sh` it is difficult to find bugs. I guess you have written `awk '...' logfilename` instead of `awk '...' "$logfilename"`.

Comment: I have added the code at the top, with your name. Pls correct it.

Comment: Can you add more lines in wrutel's code, for getting the list of failed testcases. I am adding the code ( were array arr is creating the problem ). it seems wrutel is not seeing the page.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg Why don't you try the suggestion from my comment first? If you need help with basic problems I suggest to read a basic shell script tutorial.